# javax.mail exception while sending a email from amazon server

Tags: java, email, smtp

I have a simple standalone java class that sends out the emails. I'm using javax.mail to send my emails.

When I run the class on Window machine it is working fine. When I ran the same class on Amazon Server it is giving below exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP  host: smtpout.secureserver.net, port: 25, response: 554
554 *.phx3.secureserver.net  ESMTP No Relay Access Allowed From xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I tried to find help online. for e.g. by execution below command

```
nc -z -v smtpout.secureserver.net 25
Connection to smtpout.secureserver.net 25 port [tcp/smtp] succeeded!
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use the server smtpout.secureserver.net to send mail to an address not hosted by that server, asking the server to relay that mail.

Since services like that are used by spammers to hide behind, nearly all servers block this, unless the server knows you, either because you are in his network (which you are not), or because you authenticate yourself.

I don't know why it worked with your windows machine. Maybe you were in the local network of that server, maybe the server is run by your ISP.

Here is an example on how to use smtp authentication: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0538.html

Of course you need an user and password for the server, you have to talk to whoever runs that server for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did used your example for smtp authentication. I am getting same exception when I execute the program on Amazon Server. Things are working fine when same program runs on Windows machine.

Comment: @hardy_sandy Well, for some reason the mail server won't allow you to relay mails. Who owns the server? Your ISP? Do they have a policy not to accept relay requests from outside their network?

Comment: it's  amail server from godaddy. But how come relays mails are working from Windows machine.